# Django: how to use the checkbox in the admin

Tags: django, forms, checkbox, admin

I try to display the values of checkbox in my view but It's not working..

forms.py

```
class JoursForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event

    JOURS = ( 
        (1, 'L'),
        (2, 'M'),
        (3, 'M'),
        (4, 'J'),
        (5, 'V'),
    )
    jours = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                     choices=JOURS, label= u"répéter les :")

    def clean_my_field(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['jours']
```

admin.py

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = JoursForm
    save_on_top = True
    save_as = True
    list_per_page = 25
    list_display = ('title', 'start', 'end',  'user', 'fin', 'frequency')

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('title','start', 'end', 'is_cancelled', 'calendar', 'user', 'description', ('frequency', 'fin' ), 'activated', 'jours',)
        }),
    )
```

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = JoursForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        jours = form.cleaned_data.get('jours')
        print 'jours', jours

else:
    form = JoursForm
```

I would like to use the values of checkbox but when I save in admin after having tick the boxes, they remain unchecked.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your jours selection is not saved anywhere - there is no modelfield to save it. 
To make this work you can create a model for your jours

```
class Jour(models.Model):
    abbrev = models.CharField(length="1")
```

and add your weekdays in there.

Then you add a field to your Event model:

```
jours=models.ManyToManyField(Jour)
```

Then you can just change your form to:

```
class JoursForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event

    jours = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                 queryset=Jour.objects.all(), label= u"répéter les :")
```

However, I am not sure if that is what you want to achieve.

Comment: I get the error : __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: are you getting the error in the admin or the view?

Comment: Sorry my answer is not correct - can you please post your Event model? Your Jours choices need to defined in the model, are they?

Comment: where should django admin save the jours input? There is no jours field in your model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95241/discussion-between-ger-s-brett-and-patrice).

Comment: django admin don't save the jours. No, there is no jours field in the model. if I click on the save button in the admin, I can not save jours

Comment: I added a class to the model : class Lejour(models.Model): abbrev = models.CharField(_('jours'), max_length=1, choices=JOURS) and to the class Event : jours=models.ManyToManyField(Lejour) and inside the file forms : jours = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset= Lejour.objects.all(), label= u"répéter les :"). I have no error but I can't display the checkbox in admin

Comment: You need to add in the days in the admin (first show the model in the admin and then add them in).

Comment: I added in the admin :  form = JoursForm and fieldsets = ((None, {'fields': (['jours'])}))